# Sync Facebook user data between frontend and backend

Tags: facebook, synchronization, frontend, backend

This question is of type: What is your suggestion? If it does not respect SO guideline, I am sorry.

I am developing a RESTful application that will be available in Facebook Pages. The backend is developed in PHP using [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) with [RESTful](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) library for it.

The frontend is developed using [BrunchIO](http://brunch.io/) in CoffeeScript.

The starting point of the application is `home.php`, a CodeIgniter controller, which loads a view looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>fBoutik - Shop</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <script>
        require('initialise');
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Left out other data).

When `initialise` file is loaded, some stuff is executed. including initialising a `User` Marionette (Backbone) model.

A users logs in with Facebook on the frontend and a POST is made to the server to a controller, where I set some data on SESSION.

This is a little cumbersome, because every time the app is loaded, the Facebook login dialog appears (which goes away in a moment) and a POST is made on the server.

Is there a better way to sync the user data between frontend and backend ?

If you need more details, I'll update this post.